# facebook login canceled after re-install app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I created a android app, and I try login by facebook.
I had generated release hash key, and I set the key in Facebook develop page.
It's successed.

Until I Uninstall my app, and reinstall App.
I can't login by Facebook.
It always return the error message:"Login canceled by Player"

How do I resolved it. please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet, for which you get this error.

Comment: Please provide code snippets so that we can help you more. Are you seeing any errors in LogCat that could be helpful in debugging this issue?